# On the parallelization of matrix multiplications in Mathematica 8

Tags: parallelization, linear-algebra

I have installed *Mathematica* 8, but I think the commands for parallelizations do not work! Even when I try to test the example in the Help of *Mathematica*, I face with

> ParallelDo::nopar: No parallel kernels available; proceeding with
>   sequential evaluation.

Please guide me how to resolve this problem. In fact I wish to then use `ParalledDo` in the following code to reduce the computational time:

```
ClearAll[n, A, V, Id, b, L, i, pr]
n = 1000;
A = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 3 i, {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 -> j}, {n, 
    n}];
b = SparseArray[Table[1, {i, n}]];
DA = Diagonal[A];
B = SparseArray[Table[(1/DA[[i]])^1, {i, 1, n}]];
Id = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1}, {n, n}];
V = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[B]];
ParallelDo[
VV = SparseArray[A.V];
  V = SparseArray[V].SparseArray[2 Id - VV];
  L[i] = Norm[N[SparseArray[b - SparseArray[A].SparseArray[V.b]]]];
  Print["The residual norm of the linear system solution is:" 
    Column[{i}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue]] 
    Column[{L[i]}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue]]];
  , {i, 4}] // Timing
```

I will be thankful if anyone gives me some tips to reduce the computational cost of matrix-by-matrix multiplications in the above written code.

Comment: BTW the `nopar` message suggests that you either have a single core CPU or you set Mathematica not to launch any parallel kernels.  You can launch kernels manually using `LaunchKernels` even on a single core machine.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have parallel kernels set up? This is done from the options:

[image]

You need to make sure Local Kernels are not disabled. If they're enabled and the options set as shown, then evaluating, for example, `ParallelDo[Pause[1]; f[i], {i, 4}]` without parallel kernels launched automatically launches them.